# echo $PATH in PyCharm Terminal

Tags: pycharm

Fairly new to Pycharm first of all, so thanks in advance. When I type echo $PATH in the Pycharm terminal I get:

`/Users/.../MoFilmsEnv/bin:/Users/.../.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/bin:/Users/.../.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@global/bin:/Users/.../.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Users/.../.rvm/bin`

If I'm not mistaken I believe it's suppose to be `bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:`

Thanks for your help

Comment: Did you run the same in a normal terminal? I get very similar outputs except for an additional entry for my virtualenv.

Comment: Tacuma, a fresh, vanilla *nix install may have that simple path, but as a user installs software, the path can become more complex to provide for additional install locations and change shell behavior. This answer gives some good detail on how this happens on your mac: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18014402/1089228

Answer (score 0):

`PATH` Variable is not necessarily confined to a small set of locations. Other locations can be added to it for discovering executables that needs to be run from the command line. One common practice of doing it would be to put a `export` statement in either `~/.profile` or `~/.bashrc`. Open these two files, one of them should have an entry for the Ruby paths in your output.

In PyCharm's case it also included the locations of the interpreter it is configured to use for the project like a virtual environment or the system's python installation.